# 子ViewControllerから親ViewControllerのパラメータを変更する方法

Tags: swift, uikit

Swiftのプログラム質問です。
子ViewControllerの中のViewの中にUIButtonあります。そのボタンを押すと親ViewControllerのパラメータを変更したいと思っています。

以下のように子ViewControllerを追加しています。

```
// 子ViweController(content)を追加
self.addChildViewController(content)
// 子ViewControllerのviewを自身のview階層に追加
self.view.addSubview(content.view)
// 子ViewControllerに追加が終わったことを通知する
content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

子Viewの中にあるButtonを押すと、親ViewControllerのパラメータ(例えばvar test:Integer)を変更したいと思っています。Segueのようにパラメータを受け渡せればと考えていますが、どのようにするのかわかりません。

ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

単純な方法としては、`parentViewController`で親ViewControllerを取得するものがあります。

```
func click(sender :UIButton) {
    if let vc :ParentViewController = self.parentViewController as? ParentViewController {
        vc.test = "hogehoge"
    }
}
```

Optional Binding構文で`as?`でキャストして型チェックが行えますので、インスタンス変数の可視性がinternal以上であれば、上記の記述で安全に受け渡しができると思います。

Comment: ライブラリのpageMenu(https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu)を使っています。pageMenu自身が本質問のcontentに該当する（と思った）ので質問させていただきました。
しかし、if let vc : ViewController = self.parentViewController as ViewController { としても型チェックのif内が実行されません。また、parentViewControllerではなく、presentingViewControllerを使うというページもありました。実際使ってもif内が実行されません。解決方法ご存知であれば教えてください。

Comment: これはリファレンスを参照して頂きたいのですが、`presentingViewController`はモーダル表示を行った場合の表示元ViewControllerを差します。上記コードにて一般的な親子関係にあるViewController間での値の受け渡しができることは確認しておりますので、PopMenuを使った前提でどのようなコードを書き、何が上手くいっていないのか、具体的な質問に落とし込んで頂けないと解決方法の提示は不可能です。

Comment: 失礼しました。別スレッドでPageMenuを使ったコードの質問をさせてください。